# Snowflake- date type length change

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create view on table for certain columns but looking option to change the datatype length while creating view.

Let say create table

```
create table test( a varchar(100))
```

as there option to change varchar 100 to 20 while creating view

```
create view R1 as select to_varchar(1, length(20)) ..
```

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: I think the answer is this is possible, but I'm not exactly sure what you want. Can you add more examples?

Comment: If your table allows up to 100 and your view only displays 20, you may not display all the data in the view. In that case, you can use left(MY_COLUMN_NAME, 20).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could change data type, but be  aware of possible truncation errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW R1
AS
SELECT LEFT(a, 20)::VARCHAR(20) AS a  -- taking first 20 chars to avoid truncation
FROM test;

DESCRIBE VIEW R1;
```

Option 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW R1
AS
SELECT TRY_CAST(a, VARCHAR(20)) AS a  -- string longer than 20 chars are casted as NULL
FROM test;

DESCRIBE VIEW R1;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Option2 is returning null on table column and working fine for hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view_modified AS
SELECT
COLUMN1,
SUBSTRING(COLUMN2, 1, 100) AS COLUMN2_MODIFIED,
COLUMN3
FROM
my_table;

n the above example, my_view_modified is a new view that selects the columns from my_table but modifies the length of COLUMN2 using the SUBSTRING function. The SUBSTRING function is used to extract a substring from COLUMN2 starting at position 1 and with a length of 100 characters.

By creating this new view, you can effectively change the field length on the view level. However, please note that this approach does not modify the underlying table's schema or field length. It only provides a modified representation of the data when querying the view.